# Dispensation of US767004

Tags: international, us767004

This patent, US767004, was issued to my great grandfather, Karol Muchowicz in 1904.  How can I determine whether and to whom it  was assigned?

Comment: Also corresponding Austrian patent: AT17334B

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can order these records from [www.archives.gov](http://www.archives.gov/research/guide-fed-records/groups/241.html#241.3).

Under the heading "241.3 - RECORDS OF THE PATENT OFFICE RELATING TO NUMBERED PATENTS 1836-1973" the records appear to include "...Digests relating to assignments of patent property rights, 1837-1905, with indexes, 1837-1923..."

Answer (score 0):

The [USPTO assignment search tool](http://legacy-assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat) won't be much help in this case, since it only has data from August 1980 onward.

Alternatively, from MPEP 301.01 (a)(2):

> All records of assignments of patents recorded before May 1, 1957, are maintained by the National Archives and Records Administration (NARA). The records are open to public inspection. Certified and uncertified copies of those assignment records are provided by NARA upon request and payment of the fees required by NARA."

And:

> All assignment records from 1837 to April 30, 1957 for patents are now maintained and are open for public inspection in the National Archives Research Room located at the Washington National Records Center Building, 4205 Suitland Road, Suitland, Maryland 20746.